# Cannot get the "user" property of an event

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization, google-docs

I need to get the user property of an event (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)) and I have been going nuts over this as the `result` of the following simplified script included `user` in some cases and not in others:

```
function myOnEdit(event) {
  var result = "";

  for (var key in event) {
    result = result + key + ": " + event[key] + "; ";
  }
}
```

What influences whether the event includes the user property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much struggle I realized that this is an authorization issue of sorts.

Under normal circumstances the above `myOnEdit` does not need to be authorized, and if executed manually it does not ask for authorization. It executes flawlessly -- just without the `user` info.

If, however, the following line (or something similar) appears somewhere -- anywhere -- in the script, that solves the problem:

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

The existence of this line forces the authorization request to appear when any function in the script is ran manually and once this authorization is granted, the `result` of the original `myOnEdit` will include the `user` property.

Yay!

Comment: In fact, the above results in the `user` property being available for all users who run the script (at least within the same apps domain) **without** **any** **further** authorization requests.